# Create a new workspace, really? I'm not sure I understand why/how to do this without recreating the entire workspace I have. Help!

Tags: error

This meeting was changed in your calendar and scheduling program from a nonrecurring meeting to a recurring meeting. The current workspace does not support a recurring meeting. In your scheduling program, unlink the meeting from the workspace, and then link the meeting again to a new workspace. The new workspace will automatically support a recurring meeting.